# How To Change What You've Called In A Function To An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

Suppose I create a function that flips an array's elements. For example, the function takes in [1,2,3,4] and flips it to [4,3,2,1]. My function is capable of doing that. However, I want to do something that doesn't seem to work. If I call the function like this: `flip("hello")`, I want it to change `"hello"` to an array like this: `[h,e,l,l,o]`, flip the elements to become like this: `o,l,l,e,h` then join the elements together to make it `olleh`. This is what I have been able to make so far:

```
function reverse (A) {
if(typeof(A) == 'string') { A.toString().split(" "); }
var i1 = 0;
var i2 = A.length - 1;

function swap(A, i1, i2) {
var temp = A[i1];
A[i1] = A[i2];
A[i2] = temp;
return A;

}

var index1 = 0;
var index2 = A.length - 1;
var temp = A[index1];

for(let i = index1; i < index2; i++) { 
    swap(A, i, index2); index2--;
}
console.log(A);

}
```

This does not work at all. I think that is because I am not dealing with what is being called but rather the parameter itself. I have also tried:

```
if(typeof(reverse(A)) == 'string') {A.toString().split(" "); }
```

However, that gives me a result that says: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I have been searching for an hour with no success. Any help?

Comment: `"Hello".split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: Is there a way to assign "hello" to one function? Instead of typing `"Hello".split("").reverse().join("")`, can't I just type "Hello".reverse()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
A.toString().split(" ");
```

with

```
A = A.split(""); // empty string for splitting, splits every character
```

because you need an assignment and while `A` is already an string, you do not need `toString()`.

Later you have to return the joined array with:

```
return A.join('');
```

**Methods used:**

- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

  > The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) into substrings.
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

  > The `join()` method joins all elements of an array into a string.

Complete working code with some minor changes:

```js
function reverse(a) {
    function swap(b, i1, i2) {
        var temp = b[i1];
        b[i1] = b[i2];
        b[i2] = temp;
    }

    var index1 = 0,
        index2 = a.length - 1,
        isString = typeof a === 'string';

    if (isString) {
        a = a.split("");
    }

    for (index1 = 0; index1 < index2; index1++) {
        swap(a, index1, index2);
        index2--;
    }

    return isString ? a.join('') : a;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(reverse([100, 101, 102]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(reverse('hello'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "hello";
    var splitting = str.split(""); 
    var reversed_array=splitting.reverse();
    var result=reversed_array.join("");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
</script>
</code></pre>
```

**Function that are used
split :- which will split the string into array .
reverse :- which will be used to reverse the array .
join :- It will join the reversed array**
[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [string](/questions/tagged/string)[array](/questions/tagged/array)[function](/questions/tagged/function)